# Flutter Build stopped working for Windos 7 64 Bits

Tags: flutter, windows-7, flutter-windows

I have build application which works on Android, ios, MacOS and Windows. Till not it was working on Windows 7 64 bits but since last update it has stopped working. From Windows 8 it is working.

It installs on device but when we start app, it shows error as below.

***getpointertype could not be located in the dynamic link library user32.dll***

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  http: ^0.13.4
  intl: ^0.17.0
  google_fonts: 2.2.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  provider: ^6.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.20
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
  passcode_screen: ^2.0.0
  sqlite3_flutter_libs: ^0.5.7
  sqflite_common_ffi: ^2.1.0
  firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: 9.1.3
  share_plus: ^4.0.4
  pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.1
  html: ^0.15.0
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0
  visibility_detector: ^0.2.2
  timeago: ^3.1.0
  ping_discover_network: ^0.2.0+1
  device_info_plus: ^3.1.1
  esc_pos_utils: ^1.1.0
  esc_pos_printer: ^4.1.0
  quick_usb: ^0.3.0
  pos_printer_manager: ^0.0.5
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  window_manager: ^0.0.5
  in_app_purchase: ^3.0.2
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  network_info_plus: ^2.1.2

dependency_overrides:
  archive: ^3.2.0
  printing:
  google_api_headers: ^1.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons:
flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  android: true
  ios: true


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/icon/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/qrimg/
    - i18n/
```

Comment: Actually, *your development environment must meet these minimum requirements: Operating Systems: Windows 10 or later (64-bit), x86-64 based.*

Comment: Although [Flutter supports running on Windows 7](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/supported-platforms#supported-platforms) some plugin you have installed does not. Try removing the plugins one by one and check which one is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks @lepsch for comment. Is there anyway we can check which os it will support ?